# Migration has_one and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration, database-migration

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id" #creator post
  has_many :users #followers post
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 has_many :posts 
 end
```

What command line I need to perform to migrate to perform these different relationships between the User and Post tables?
 Thanks

Comment: how to set up the migration you're asking?

Comment: Yes, I am unable to set it up ....

Comment: you already have these tables `posts` and `users`?

Comment: yes the tables and users posts are already present

Comment: consider `has_many through`. `create_table :game_users, id: false do |t|
  t.references :post_id, null: false, index: true
  t.references :user_id, null: false, index: true
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post` should **`belong_to`**`:owner`, because the `posts` table has the foreign key. Also, its `#users` is a bit too ambiguously named, as is `User#posts`.

Here are your models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :owned_posts # foreign_key: :owner_id will be inferred
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :followers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :followed_posts
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_posts, class_name: 'Post', inverse_of: :owner
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :followed_posts, through: :subscriptions, source: :post, class_name: 'Post', inverse_of: :followers
end
```

And here are the migrations to support them:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      # ...
    end
  end
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.integer :owner_id
      # ...
    end
  end
end

class CreateSubscriptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :subscriptions do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

**If it weren't for the 'ownership' relation,** you could use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship:

1. rename the `subscriptions` migration to `posts_users` (must be plurals in alphabetical order),
2. do away with its model entirely, and
3. have `Post.has_and_belongs_to_many :users` and `User.has_and_belongs_to_many :posts`.

In fact, you technically *could* do that, but having ambiguous names like that is bad practice.

Comment: thank you very much but I have a problem when I create a new "subscription", the post ID is not save perhaps that the problem come from:    `def subscription_params
               params.require(:subscription).permit(:user_id, :post_id)
             end`

Comment: That sounds like a separate question. I think you'd most likely not want to manipulate subscriptions directly, but use things like `@post.followers << current_user` in an action on the *posts* controller.

Comment: `@post.followers << current_user` generate error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Post::Follower`.    When i create a subscription i have this error: `Unpermitted parameter: post_id
`I checked several times the settings are correct though!

Comment: Hmm. You've got `source: :user` or `class_name: 'User'` in `Post.has_many :followers`?

Comment: I have `source: :user` in Post model

Comment: I have succesfully fix error: `Unpermitted parameter: post_id` but have always the error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Post::Follower`. I can use `@post.subscriptions` its work !

Comment: Does it work if you put `class_name: 'User'` back in?

Comment: When i use class_name: "User" i have this error: `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "follower" or :followers in model Subscription. Try 'has_many :followers, :through => :subscriptions, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or post?` I need to put class_name and the source? (The two together?)

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's both.

Comment: Thank you very much, this kind of relationship is quite complex to do, but thank you very much for your help